# Perfect maps and open subsets

Tags: general-topology

Consider $f:X\to Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are Tychonoff spaces, and suppose that $f$ is a perfect map. We say that $f$ is a perfect map if it is continuous, closed, surjective and $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact for every $y\in Y$.

I have the following problem:

Prove that if $U\subseteq X$ is open and $f^{-1}(\{y\})\subseteq U$, then there exists an open subset $V$ of $Y$ such that $y\in V$ and $f^{-1}(V)\subseteq U$.

I don't know how to find a such open $V$. First, I thought maybe we need to suppose something else about $f$ or $U$... What do you think?

Thanks.

Comment: you mean $U\subset X$?

Comment: @StefanH. Yeah, I edited it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is closed, so $F = f(X\setminus U)$ is closed. $y\notin F$, since $f^{-1}(\{y\}) \subset U$. Hence $V = Y\setminus F$ is open and contains $y$. $f$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open neighbourhood of $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ that doesn't intersect $X\setminus U$, in other words, is contained in $U$.

Comment: @Talexius: Actually this property is equivalent to the closedness of $f$. You need neither the compact fibers nor the Tychonoff of $X$ and $Y.$

Comment: Oh, thank you @StefanH. Actually, I was trying to use that the fiber $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact :S